# Hiding Element in React Based on SCSS/CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, next.js

I have a global element that needs to be hidden only on a specific page.
The problem I encounter is that when I try to hide the element on a specific page base on importing the css, it also hides on all pages. It needs to hide only on this page. The `<Main />` page is where my main pages are located like the `/products`

```
<body>
  <Main />
  <div style={{ height: 800, position: "absolute" }} className="products">
    Hide this on none /products page
  </div>
</body>
```

**products.scss**

```
body {
  .products {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

**Product**

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Products = () => {
  const router = useRouter()

  if (router.pathname === '/products') {
    require('../styles/products.scss')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style={{ height: 800, position: "absolute" }} className={router.pathname === '/products' ? 'hidden' : ''}>
    Hide this on none /products page
  </div>
```

and now set `display: none;` for the `hidden` class. :)